# How to remove some characters or words from the middle of a string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am using .NET 2.1, i need to remove some extra parts of a string, but the issue is that these parts do not occur in the beginning nor in the end. they come in between. for instance we have:-

> Ali and Ahmed are very very good friends.

but i want

> Ali and Ahmed are very good friends.

I know the occurrence of the problem. Is there a way i can remove the word 'very' from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `source.Replace("very",string.Empty);`

`String.Replace(oldString,newString)` with the second parameter setted to string.Empty is the same as remove from the source string all "oldString".

Comment: This will leave double spaces between the words `very  good`. They could replace `"very "` or `" very"` to avoid this.

Comment: You are right @pappbence96 it doesn't remove the spaces

Answer (score 3):

You can try *regular expressions*:

To remove consequent duplicates of `"very"`:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ... 

  string source = "Ali and Ahmed are very very good friends.";

  string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"(very)(\s+\1)+", match => match.Groups[1].Value);
```

To remove consequent duplicates of *any* words:

```
  string source = "Ali and Ahmed are are are very very good friends.";

  string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"(\w+)(\s+\1)+", match => match.Groups[1].Value);
```

In both cases, the `result` is

```
  Ali and Ahmed are very good friends.
```

Comment: Assuming the use-case is, indeed, to remove duplicate words, excellent answer +1

Comment: @Dmitry i was not taking about duplicate words. i was just asking how to remove any word which i want to, from a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the starting index and the end index of the part you want to remove you can use this methode

```
public static string Delete(string str, int start, int end) 
{
    return str.Substring(0, start)
         + str.Substring(end, str.Length-end);
}
```

here is end the exclusive index of the part that is to deleted
e.g.

```
Delete("0123456789",3,5) -> "01256789"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY89D4JADIb3@xWNE8ST@P0R42B01MnBwTgcZ4OXYCF3xcQQfjtygItd2r552r7VbqQzizWpF7pcaYR9nkMp8iJOjQadKue8VNa94lhxm6yhBI6YImPQd02SYIg9ZLkrkR4hiFJAExa5sOSx6FLE3VAwlh0etkgbwz@k2SFb6YSU8HPkd25F9WfpnZkHnJWh3s7tDsomLizFzx7sYDCeTGfzxXK13gy24vJxjK/okJHLUoyu1jCeDGHw@0vCTMIi9Neqqv4C)